# How to populate data from .txt file into Excel in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, text, file

I'm trying to create something to read data from a .txt file, then populate data into .xls, but after open the .txt file, how do I get the data out? Basically I'm trying to get the the third column of the lines dated '04/06/2010'. After I open the .txt file, when I use `ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col)`, the `ActiveSheet` is not pointing to .txt file.

My .txt file is like this (space delimited):

```
04/05/10 23 29226
04/05/10 24 26942
04/06/10 1 23166
04/06/10 2 22072
04/06/10 3 21583
04/06/10 4 21390
```

Here is the code I have:

```
Dim BidDate As Date

BidDate = '4/6/2010'

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=ForecastFile, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True

If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox ("The forecast file " & ForecastFile & " was not found.")
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0


Dim row As Integer, col As Integer


row = 1
col = 1

cell_value = activeSheet.Cells(row, col)
MsgBox ("the cell_value=" & cell_value)

Do While (cell_value  <> BidDate) And (cell_value <> "")
    row = row + 1
    cell_value = activeSheet.Cells(row, col)
   ' MsgBox ("the value is " & cell_value)
Loop

If cell_value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("A load forecast for " & BidDate & " was not found in your current load forecast file titled '" + ForecastFile + ". " + "Make sure you have a load forecast for the current bid date and then open this spreadsheet again.")
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Can anyone point out where it goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, I set the variable ws equal to the sheet I want and I'm able to use that variable to refer to the sheet later.  The keyword ActiveWorkbook should point to the newly opened text file.  I could tell what you wanted to do with the info, such I just made some stuff up.

```
Sub GetBidData()

    Dim dtBid As Date
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFile As String

    dtBid = #4/6/2010#
    sFile = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents\ForecastFile.txt"

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sFile, _
        StartRow:=1, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Space:=True
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Set rFound = ws.Columns(1).Find( _
        Format(dtBid, ws.Range("A1").NumberFormat), , xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox rFound.Value & vbCrLf & _
            rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value & vbCrLf & _
            rFound.Offset(0, 2).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I should add that I didn't encounter any error with your code, it just didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally avoid using the ActiveWorkbook object unless you're positive that the workbook you want to reference will *always* be active when your code is run. Instead, you should set the workbook you're working with to a variable. Theoretically, you should be able to use the OpenText method to do this, but VBA doesn't like that. (I'm pretty sure it's a bug.) So right after you open your text file, I would do this:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Forecastfile, StartRow:=1, 
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True

Dim ForecastWorkbook As Workbook, book As Workbook
Dim ForecastFileName As String

ForecastFileName = "YourFileNameHere.txt"

For Each book In Application.Workbooks

    If book.Name = ForecastFileName Then

        Set ForecastWorkbook = book
        Exit For

    End If

Next book
```

Then, instead of this...

```
cell_value = activeSheet.Cells(row, col)
```

...do this...

```
cell_value = ForecastWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(row, col).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will read the text file and paste the values in the cell of Sheet2. However if you put a formatting in the Date column that will do the trick

```
Public Sub Read_text()
Sheet2.Activate
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename
x = 1
y = 1
Set Stream = fso.OpenTextFile(Fname, ForReading, True)
Do While Not Stream.AtEndOfStream
          Str_text = Stream.ReadLine 'Perform your actions
          rdtext = Split(Str_text, " ")
          Sheet2.Cells(x, y) = rdtext(0)
          Sheet2.Cells(x, y + 1) = rdtext(1)
          Sheet2.Cells(x, y + 2) = rdtext(2)
          x = x + 1
          y = 1
Loop
Stream.Close
End Sub
```

For example : Below code will change the format in '05/04/2010'

```
Sheet2.Cells(x, y) = Format(rdtext(0), "mm/dd/yyyy;@")
```

Comment: It is always also explain your answer, rather than just dump code.